# Strange CSS width in floating point after last Chrome update

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, floating

After last Chrome update version 83.0.4103.61 I got strange behaviour of 'width' property for some of my elements. For some elements where the 'width' is not strictly defined by CSS the real width is in floating point number like 125.487px. Due to that I see some vizual glitches for buttons, menus, ... If I will try to manualy set the width to exact valuethen it looks good.

Is there a way to push Chrome to not use floating point numbers?

[image]

For better understanding I add a picture. When I manually change the width of button to 81px or 82px it is fine. But if it is something in the middle then 1px is missing. It sounds to me like a space of 82px is reserved but then only 81px are rendered and one px is just missing.

Comment: Chrome will round those numbers anyway visually AFAIK...the decimals are just for information.

Comment: But something changed after last update. I have a CSS style for buttons. Some buttons are ok some not. It looks like it depends on the size of the text inside the buttons. If I will fix this by inspection tool it is ok. And it does not matter if I will round it up or down. So I do not believe that the decimals are just for info.

Comment: How do you know the glitches you see are due to the non-integer widths? If you replace the non-integer widths with integer widths, do the glitches still occur?

Comment: By the way, “125.487” is not floating-point. For something to be floating-point, it must have a point that floats. This occurs in representation formats where there is an exponent that specifies where the decimal or radix point goes. “125.487” is simply a numeral for a number that is not an integer.

Comment: Yes if I will replace it by integer then the glitch disappear.

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem. I wonder if you get any solution for this... Thanks